# R - glmnet - cross validated - AUC

Tags: r, glmnet, auc

I have just started working with the glmnet package in R. I have s a dataset which has about 130,000 features and about 32000 rows of data. Here is the code to create the model

```
myModel = cv.glmnet(data.matrix(modelData), modelData$ACTION,family = "binomial",type.measure = "auc",nfolds = 5,alpha = 1)
```

My question is, is it possible to print the final auc for this model? Can someone provide any sample code?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R, not statistics.

Comment: okay moved the question to stackoverflow

Comment: Can you link the SO question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `cv.glment` cvm: The mean cross-validated error - a vector of length length(lambda).  Try `max(myModel$cvm)` and `summary(myModel$cvm)`.

Comment: I see but how do I use cvm to get the auc value?

Comment: @abhi: If the`type.measure` function you're using is auc, then cvm IS the auc.  `cv.glmnet` fits a whole sequence of models, and will report the auc for all of them.  The max of the cvm sequence is the best model's auc.  Please take some time to read the documentation for `glmnet`, it's very good.

Comment: I realized that belatedly. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: And when `cvm` does store AUC... does `lambda.min` then refer to the value of lambda that gives the *maximum* AUC? Or still the minimum?

Comment: yes, it gives the lambda that maximizes the auc. 
I also read that it computes the weighted AUC if you give cv.glmnet some weights.